# Consider a three points M1,M2 and M3 that are not on the same line.Write the equation of the line L1 passing through the points M1 and M2.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Consider a three points $M1,M2$ and $M3$ that are not on the same line.Write the equation of the line $L1$ passing through the points $M1$ and $M2$. Write the equation of the plane $α$ passing through the line $L1$ and the point $M3$. Write the equation of the plane $β$ passing through the point $M3$ and perpendicular to the plane $α$. Find the symmetric (canonical) equation of the line $L2$ that is intersection of planes of $α$ and $β$. Determine the coordinates of the point $A$ of intersection of lines $L1$ and $L2$. Draw the corresponding figure.

Give me a little hint

Comment: Hints : 1) it is not "the" equation of line $L_1$ but  the equationS $x=...; y=...$. 2) You can find the equation of the plane $\alpha$ directly as being the plane passing through $M_1,M_2,M_3$.

Comment: You don't say if you can use coordinates $x_k,y_k,z_k$ of points $M_k$... Otherwise, for your first question, the  line passing through $M_1$ and $M_2$ is the set of points $M$ of the form $M= tM_1+(1-t)M_2$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$...

Comment: Any comment ?....